# How to use Appium in NativeScript code sharing project?

Tags: angular, jasmine, mocha.js, appium, nativescript

I have a code sharing NativeScript project with Angular that uses Jasmine for unit testing. I'm trying to add [nativescript-dev-appium](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium), so I can use Appium for UI/e2e testing on web and native platforms.

The resulting setup uses Mocha, which clashes with Jasmine. I get “duplicate identifier” errors because of the duplicate typings, and now I have two frameworks that essentially serve the same purpose (as far as I understand it).

Is it possible to use Jasmine with Appium instead of Mocha? Or do I have to change my unit tests to use Mocha? What is the correct way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm remembering right, you have to specify the types which should be used by setting the **types** property of your **tsconfig.json** in your root folder. This way typescript only uses jasmine. For Example like this:

```
tsconfig.json
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types" : ["...", "...", "jasmine"]
    }
}
```

Your **e2e-folder** has a **tsconfig.json** too. You have to add the types property in that file too:

```
e2e/tsconfig.json
...
"types": [
            "node",
            "mocha",
            "chai"
        ],
```

You also have to **exclude** the e2e-folder from your root tsconfig.json so that typescript doesn't try to load the tsconfig.json from the e2e-folder.

```
...
"exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "e2e"
]
```

That way you can use jasmine for your unit tests and mocha for appium.
You can read more about how to specify the types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).